# jQuery: Retrieving the id of DOM on click only returns id from first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML, which is appended sometime after the page is loaded.

I have the following JS, which I am attempting to retrieve the id of the clicked label or rather the input id that it is associated with.

```js
function answerSelect(){
     $("body").on("click", "li label", function(){
      let selectedAnswer = $("input").attr("id");
      console.log(selectedAnswer);
     })
}
answerSelect();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="questions-container">
    <form>
      <ul>
        <h2 class="question">This is a question?</h2>
        <li>
          <input id="first" type="radio" name="answer-choice" required>
          <label for="first">1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="second" type="radio" name="answer-choice">
          <label for="second">2</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="third" type="radio" name="answer-choice">
          <label for="third">3</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="fourth" type="radio" name="answer-choice">
          <label for="fourth">4</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button class ="start submit btn"><h2>Submit</h2></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Currently, when inspecting the console within Chrome, it looks like it doesn't matter which label that I click; the console only prints the id "first" which is the first `li`. How can I make it so it retrieves the corresponding `li` clicked?

Comment: make fiddle to get more answer quickly... but before that use $(this).attr("id") instead of $("input").attr("id");

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will look up fiddle. I have tried using $(this).attr("id"), but I get undefined from the console.log. Maybe the id value I get back is not a string that can be printed? How can I check it is working properly?

Comment: @Eddie when you're typing a question instead of typing it in a code block, if you're using JS, HTML, or CSS you can create a snippet by clicking on one of the options in the toolbar, this let's people debug your code faster

Answer (score 1):

Use a `change` listener instead (so that both clicks on the `input` *and* clicks on the `label` will trigger the listener), and then use the `:checked` psuedo-selector to get to the `input` that's checked:

```js
$("body").on("change", "li > input", function(e) {
  let selectedAnswer = $("input:checked").attr("id");
  console.log(selectedAnswer);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questions-container">
  <form>
    <ul>
      <h2 class="question">This is a question?</h2>
      <li>
        <input id="first" type="radio" name="answer-choice" required>
        <label for="first">1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="second" type="radio" name="answer-choice">
        <label for="second">2</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="third" type="radio" name="answer-choice">
        <label for="third">3</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="fourth" type="radio" name="answer-choice">
        <label for="fourth">4</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="start submit btn"><h2>Submit</h2></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. If you don't mind can you explain the purpose of "li > * "? I am not sure how to google this. I am assuming, "listen for changes on li's within everything on page?" For the e parameter as well, what is the purpose?

Comment: It's a selector string, just like `li label`. `li > *` means "every element which is a child of a `li`". (could have also used `li input, li label` but that's more verbose)

Comment: do you think change event is useful for label? I think Yu Miao solution is better bacause he take target element from event, and you are searching input:cheked

Comment: @ArikneKrol A click on the label will trigger the `input` being checked, and the `input` being checked will trigger the `change` event :)

Comment: but you set handler for event "change" for label too. it is useless

Comment: @ArikneKrol Oh, I see what you mean, yes, you're right. Even if the listener is only listening for `li > input`, it'll still trigger for when the label is clicked. Best to change selector to `li > input`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

modify `answerSelect()` method:

```
function answerSelect() {
  $("body").on("click", "li input", function(e) {
    let selectedAnswer = e.target.id;
    console.log(selectedAnswer);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if your Elelemt ordering doesnt change this will serve the purpose

```
$("body").on("click", "li label", function(){
        let selectedAnswer =$(this).prev().attr("id");
        console.log(selectedAnswer);
 });
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrfajg4q/)

Answer (score 0):

replace your below code:

```
function answerSelect(){
    $("body").on("click", "li label", function(){
        let selectedAnswer = $("input").attr("id");
        console.log(selectedAnswer);
    })
}
```

with,

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type='radio']", function(){

        let selectedAnswer = $("input").attr("id");
        console.log(selectedAnswer);
    })
```